# How do I find out the correct amount of video RAM of a radeon card when using the open source driver?

Tags: graphics, memory, ram, radeon

I was surprised that lspci and the nvidia x server settings application didn't give me the same amount of video memory for my nvidia card. A bit of googling brought me to [this site](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604448). There it says that lspci doesn't show all the video memory.

So for the nvidia cards I can use the nvidia x server settings application to find out the correct amount of video memory but how do I do it for a radeon card when using the open source radeon driver?

Answer (score 0):

You could install the proprietary driver, get what you need from AMD Catylyst Control Panel and then uninstall.  Kinda messy, but it works...

Comment: It'd be helpful to include a link to instructions about how to do this.